# beginner, Cannot access array, codeigniter 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am unable to access my array.

I have a URL like:

http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index2/

Country2 method is as follows:

```
public function country_index2($sort_by = 'country_id', $sort_order='ASC', $offset = 0){

    $this->load->model('model_admin');

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    /* This Application Must Be Used With BootStrap 3 *  */
    $config['full_tag_open']    = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close']   ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open']   = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['base_url']         = 'http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index';
    $config['total_rows']       = $this->db->get('mhcountry')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page']         = 10; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data['pagination']         = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
                                // table, limit, offset
    // $data['query']              = $this->db->get('mhcountry', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['query']              = $this->model_admin->search_countries($config['per_page'] , $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);

    $data['templateVersion']    = 'template1';
    $data['headerVersion']      = 'header1';
    $data['navBarVersion']      = 'navbar1';
    $data['main_content']       = 'detail-wrap/admin/country_index'; 
    $data['page_title' ]        = 'example.com - App';
    $data['footerVersion']      = 'footer1';
   // $data['num_rows']           =  $this->db->get('mhcountry')->num_rows();
    //if(empty($page_number)) $page_number = 1;
    //$offset = ($page_number-1) * $config['per_page'];

    //var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view('detail-wrap/includes/template1', $data);

}
```

The contents of search_countries function is as follows:

```
function search_countries($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order){

    // you can also do this with if then else
    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'DESC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $sort_columns = array('country_id', 'country');

    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'country';

    // results query
    $query = $this->db->select('country', 'country_id')
            ->from('mhcountry')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $results['rows'] = $query->get()->result();

    $query_count = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)->from('mhcountry');
    // $tmp = $query_count->get()->result();
    //$results->[num_rows] =$tmp[0]->count;
    return $results;

    #print_r($results);
    #die;

}
```

For my view, I have this:

```
    <div class="bs-example">

                        Found 
                        <?php
                            echo $num_rows ;
                        ?>
                        Countries
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Country ID</th>
                                    <th>Country Name</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php
                                //print_r(data[$query]);


                                //foreach ($query->result() as $row ) {

                                    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row ) {


                                ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['country_id']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
                                    <td>Carter</td>
                                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                    </div>
```

[snip]

when I dump print_r($results) I get below:

```
Array ( [rows] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Canada ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Japan ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Korea ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [country] => 0 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [country] => pakist ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [country] => ddsdsd ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [country] => texas ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [country] => scotland ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [country] => scotland ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [country] => scotland ) ) )
```

But I just cannot seem to access them to display them in the view.  The view does not show the countries.

[edit]
I think what is happening is that I am passing a multidimensional array and simply having difficulty accessing the data.  I found a similar thread here [Accessing Multidimensional array with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781324/accessing-multidimensional-array-with-codeigniter)

**** NEW UPDATE ****

Please note that the method "function country_index2(...)" works as-is and does return results to the controller.  The controller is also clearly sending the results to the view.  The problem I am having is not being able to display the results in the view.  Just wanted to clear that up.

Yes, there are lines talking about sorting and pagination but that is not implemented yet and as good as just sitting there doing nothing.  Pleased to hear.

Comment: As you can see, the response is an object. Just replace your $row['country_id'] with $row->country_id

Comment: It will not work your pagination.you will get `$sort_by=2` when you are at page 2.

Comment: In regards to pagination, that is another issue.  I am still trying to view the data on a page.

Answer (score 0):

The `print_r($results)` is an array containing objects.

You can loop it like this:

```
foreach ($results['rows'] as $row) {
```

...and then access the properties of `$row` like this:

```
$row->country
```

Comment: I believe my data is sent to my view by $data['query'].  In my view, I have run print_r($query); and I can see my data as follows:  Array ( [rows] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Canada ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Japan ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [country] => Korea ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [country] => 0 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [country] => pakist ) 

BTW, I see [country] but do not see [country_id]... any significance?

Comment: Hmm, have just done a var_dump($query) and received below.  I cannot see [country_id] although I think the number is there... strange.... 

array(1) { ["rows"]=> array(10) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "Canada" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["country"]=> string(5) "Japan" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["country"]=> string(5) "Korea" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#24 (1) { ["country"]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "pakist" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "ddsdsd" }

Comment: Well, found one error.  i had country_id and country in the wrong order here...  $query = $this->db->select('country_id', 'country')
    ->from('mhcountry')
    ->limit($limit, $offset)
    ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

Still cannot get the data to output in the view though.

Comment: If you can see country_id in the output as you posted in the end of your original post, you can access it like in the above example, for example `$row->country_id` (inside the foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Because in your controller you already set the result in your `$data` array, and passed you view section.

```
$data['query'] = $this->model_admin->search_countries($config['per_page'] , $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);
```

And if you checked your module then `$query->get()->result();` provides you the data object not array.

Should be:

```
<?php 
 if( is_array($query) && count( $query ) > 0  ) :
 foreach ($query['rows'] as $row ) { ?>

 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row->country_id; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->country; ?></td>
     <td>Carter</td>
     <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
 </tr>
<?php } 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the above and I get the following error:

    A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/country_index.php

Line Number: 41

Line 41 starts as follows:

foreach ($query['rows'] as $row ) {

         ?>

                  <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row->country_id; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row->country; ?></td>
                      <td>Carter</td>
                      <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <?php } ?>

Comment: @user3264461 do you have `$this->load->view('detail-wrap/includes/template1', $data);` in your controller?

Comment: Yes, that was shown in the original post.  

This is executed and confirmed working.

$data['query']              = $this->model_admin->search_countries($config['per_page'] , $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);

Among other things, data is returned to the with this;

 $this->load->view('detail-wrap/includes/template1', $data);

When I execute following in the view:

print_r($query);

I do see an array with the data (countries and id) as posted far above.

Pleased to hear.

Comment: user3264461 - sorry, what do you mean, "in my view, if I use"?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep your code as it is. Just fix this function

```
 function search_countries($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order){

    //your other codes here
    //$query.....
    //$results['rows'] = $query->get()->result();//replace it as bellow     
    $results = $query->get(); 
    return $results;  
}
```

**Notice**
This line has no effect inside your search_countries function

```
$query_count = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)->from('mhcountry');
```

Hope it will solve your current problem.

**Warining**
Remember your pagination will not work as your current design

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors.  The first error was in the method search_countries();  The active record syntax was incorrect.

Before:

```
 $query = $this->db->select('country', 'country_id')
        ->from('mhcountry')
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

After:

```
 $query = $this->db->select('country_id country')
        ->from('mhcountry')
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

The second error was in the VIEW.  As I am receiving an object and not an array, the view loop should look like this:

```
                                <tbody>

                                <?php

                                //var_dump($query);
                                foreach ($query as $row ) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row->country_id; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row->country; ?></td>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                    <td>someone</td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
```

Thank you for all the assistance.  It is working now.